# Are Spring Controllers Thread-Safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I am writing a private utility method in a Spring Controller.

I need to use either `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`.  The former is thread-safe, the latter is not, but the latter is much faster.

Basically, it looks like this:

```
private String buildTextToDisplay() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append( ... );
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Obviously, I don't want two sessions to call this simultaneously and return garbage.

Comment: might be useful: [How do I prove programmatically that StringBuilder is not threadsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558432)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `sb` is a local variable, it doesn't need to be thread safe. (Each thread would have its own reference to a unique `StringBuilder`, right?)

Answer (score 5):

Thread-safety of a `StringBuffer` is useful when it is used as a member variable of a class. But if it is a local variable, then `StringBuilder` is better because there is no concept of thread-safety for a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use the builder in a very specific way to notice the speed difference between `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`. In 99% of use cases there is no observable difference and with modern JIT's it is 100% due to **lock elision**.

But, as others notice, you are free to use `StringBuilder` in your case.