# How do I prove programmatically that StringBuilder is not threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, stringbuilder

How do I prove programmatically that `StringBuilder` is not threadsafe?

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
public class Threadsafe {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long startdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

        MyThread1 mt1 = new MyThread1();
        Thread t = new Thread(mt1);
        MyThread2 mt2 = new MyThread2();
        Thread t0 = new Thread(mt2);
        t.start();
        t0.start();
        t.join();
        t0.join();
        long enddate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time = enddate - startdate;
        System.out.println(time);
    }

    String str = "aamir";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);

    public void updateme() {
        sb.deleteCharAt(2);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    public void displayme() {
        sb.append("b");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}

class MyThread1 implements Runnable {
    Threadsafe sf = new Threadsafe();

    public void run() {
        sf.updateme();
    }
}

class MyThread2 implements Runnable {
    Threadsafe sf = new Threadsafe();

    public void run() {
        sf.displayme();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious: _why_ would you want to prove that something is _not_ thread-safe?

Comment: `Threadsafe sf = new Threadsafe()` (in both your thread classes) => That means, your two threads are operating on different `Threadsafe` instances and thus on different `StringBuilder` instances!

Comment: https://coderanch.com/t/666742/java/understand-StringBuffer-thread-safe-StringBuilder

Comment: `curl https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html | grep "not safe for use by multiple threads" && echo "Not thread safe"`. It's documented not to be thread safe. You might not be able to prove it's not thread safe because the implementation might have changed so that it is; you shouldn't rely upon that property though, because there is no guarantee that it will continue to be thread-safe.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Likely because some colleague claims their multithreaded code using StringBuilder is perfectly safe and the question author wants to prove them wrong.

Comment: Make your StringBuilder static; that'll guarantee it's shared.

Comment: One principal caveat: Concurrency problems tend to be elusive. You may not run into errors even though the class is not threadsafe. It's sometimes very hard to find such errors.

Comment: @Philipp: Even more likely -- this is a homework problem that the OP actually attempted before asking about on StackOverflow (if so, good for you OP!)

Comment: @Philipp I hope not. If something is not documented to be thread safe, it simply *is* not...

Comment: To *prove* that it is not thread-safe requires you to inspect the implementation and give an example of two possible serialisations of operations on multiple threads that will give different results. You probably don't want to *prove* it isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 114):

### Problem

I am afraid the test you have written is incorrect.

The main requirement is to share the same [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instance between different threads. Whereas you are creating a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object for each thread.

The problem is that a `new Threadsafe()` initialises a `new StringBuilder()`:

```
class Threadsafe {
    ...
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    ...
}
class MyThread1 implements Runnable {
    Threadsafe sf = new Threadsafe();
    ...
}
class MyThread2 implements Runnable {
    Threadsafe sf = new Threadsafe();
    ...
}
```

### Explanation

To prove the [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class is not thread-safe, you need to write a test where `n` threads (`n > 1`) append some stuff to the same instance simultaneously.

Being aware of the size of all the stuff you are going to append, you will be able to compare this value with the result of [`builder.toString().length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString--):

```
final long SIZE = 1000;         // max stream size

final StringBuilder builder = Stream
        .generate(() -> "a")    // generate an infinite stream of "a"
        .limit(SIZE)            // make it finite
        .parallel()             // make it parallel
        .reduce(new StringBuilder(), StringBuilder::append, (b1, b2) -> b1);
                                // put each element in the builder

Assert.assertEquals(SIZE, builder.toString().length());
```

Since it is actually not thread-safe, you may have trouble getting the result.

An [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) may be thrown because of the `char[] AbstractStringBuilder#value` array and the allocation mechanism which was not designed for multithreading use.

### Test

Here is my [JUnit 5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.0.3) test which covers both [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html):

```
public class AbstractStringBuilderTest {

    @RepeatedTest(10000)
    public void testStringBuilder() {
        testAbstractStringBuilder(new StringBuilder(), StringBuilder::append);
    }

    @RepeatedTest(10000)
    public void testStringBuffer() {
        testAbstractStringBuilder(new StringBuffer(), StringBuffer::append);
    }

    private <T extends CharSequence> void testAbstractStringBuilder(T builder, BiFunction<T, ? super String, T> accumulator) {
        final long SIZE = 1000;
        final Supplier<String> GENERATOR = () -> "a";

        final CharSequence sequence = Stream
                .generate(GENERATOR)
                .parallel()
                .limit(SIZE)
                .reduce(builder, accumulator, (b1, b2) -> b1);

         Assertions.assertEquals(
                SIZE * GENERATOR.get().length(),    // expected
                sequence.toString().length()        // actual
         );
    }

}
```

### Results

```
AbstractStringBuilderTest.testStringBuilder: 
    10000 total, 165 error, 5988 failed, 3847 passed.

AbstractStringBuilderTest.testStringBuffer:
    10000 total, 10000 passed.
```

Comment: Wow, that's a much higher rate of errors and failures than I would have expected in the `StringBuilder` case.  What a nice demonstration.

Comment: Good idea using a parallel stream instead of using threads directly. That makes the test much shorter.

Comment: @JohnBollinger on my system, the failure rate is even higher, `>9900`…

Comment: @Holger, I also was surprised to see such a low failure rate, did you use any JVM flags?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko no, just 64bit JVM on Windows with 8 cores; no special setup.

Answer (score 18):

Much  simpler:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
IntStream.range(0, 10)
         .parallel()
         .peek(sb::append) // don't do this! just to prove a point...
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toList());

if (sb.toString().length() != 10) {
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

There will be no order of the digits (they will not be `012...` and so on), but this is something you don't care about. All you care is that not *all* the digits from range `[0..10]` where added to `StringBuilder`.

On the other hand if you replace `StringBuilder` with `StringBuffer`, you will always get 10 elements in that buffer (but out of order).

Comment: While this may work, it misses an explanation why OP's code did prove the opposite.

Comment: OP only asked for a proof; OP never asked why their code didn't work

Comment: @WordsLikeJared: true, but that explanation makes it a better answer. See the highly upvoted answer by Andrew

Answer (score 11):

Consider the following test.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class NotThreadSafe {

    private static final int CHARS_PER_THREAD = 1_000_000;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;

    private StringBuilder builder;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStringBuilder() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Runnable appender = () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < CHARS_PER_THREAD; i++) {
                builder.append('A');
            }
        };
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
        List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
            futures.add(executorService.submit(appender));
        }
        for (Future<?> future : futures) {
            future.get();
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        String builtString = builder.toString();
        Assert.assertEquals(CHARS_PER_THREAD * NUMBER_OF_THREADS, builtString.length());
    }
}
```

This is intended to prove that `StringBuilder` is not thread-safe by [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) method. When run, it always throws exception like following:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 73726

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at NotThreadSafe.testStringBuilder(NotThreadSafe.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 73726
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:650)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
    at NotThreadSafe.lambda$testStringBuilder$0(NotThreadSafe.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Therefore, `StringBuilder` is broken when used by multiple threads.

Comment: While this may work, it misses an explanation why OP's code did prove the opposite.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The question asked in the title is how to proof that it is broken, not why the code from the op demonstrates the problem

Comment: @Ferrybig:  true, but that explanation makes it a better answer. See the highly upvoted answer by Andrew